# ListBox с переопределенным ItemsPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть `ListBox`, который использует `Canvas` в качестве панели.

Возникло несколько вопросов при использовании контрола в таком виде:

1) Как задавать координаты элементов на Canvas декларативно?
В таком виде, как у меня, не работает.

2) Элемент не теряет выделение после его выбора, если кликать в пустую область `Canvas`. То есть он так и остается `IsSelected = true`. Как изменить такое поведение?
Обрабатывать клик по канвасу?

Xaml:

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Text}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Items>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="45" Text="Кнопка"/>
         </ListBox.Items>
     </ListBox>
```

Comment: Просто любопытно - зачем это могло понадобиться ? :)

Comment: По поводу п.2, полагаю, что его лучше разместить отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве обходного способа решения используйте `Tag` чтобы сохранить значение а дальше уже добавляете требуемую привязку к `ItemContainerStyle`.

Пример

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Tag}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <TextBlock Tag="45" Text="Кнопка" />
            <TextBlock Tag="90" Text="Кнопка2" />
            <TextBlock Tag="150" Text="Кнопка3" />
            <TextBlock Tag="280" Text="Кнопка4" />
        </ListBox.Items>
```

Если вы хотите задать несколько параметров, а не только один, то используйте конвертер значений.